# How to submit data of a flash form? [python]

Tags: python, flash, forms

I would like to know if it is possible to submit a flash form from python and, if it is, how?
I have done form submitting from python before, but the forms were HTML not flash. I really have no idea on how to do this. In my research about this I kept getting 'Ming'. However, Ming is only to create .swf files and that's not what I intend to do.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the url attribute (I think it's url, please correct me if I'm wrong) on a Flash form control to a Python script - then it will pass it through HTTP POST like any normal HTML form.

You've got nothing to be afraid of, it uses the same protocol to communicate, it's just a different submission process.

Answer (score 0):

For your flash app, there's no difference if the backend is python, php or anything, so you can follow a normal "php + flash contact form" guide and then build the backend using django or any other python web framework, receive the information from the http request (GET or POST, probably the last one) and do whatever you wanted to do with them.

Notice the response from python to flash works the same as with php, it's just http content, so you can use XML or even better, JSON.